# knex migration:latest cannot connect while psql works fine

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, postgresql-9.5

I need help figuring out why I can't run knex migration on my local machine 
 using. It seems that knex has some trouble connecting to the postgres database. Running `knex migration:latest` in the terminal gives me this error:

```
⇒  knex migrate:latest
Using environment: development
Error: Unable to acquire a connection
at Client_PG.acquireConnection (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:332:40)
at Runner.ensureConnection (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:233:24)
at Runner.run (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:47:42)
at SchemaBuilder.Target.then (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:39:43)
at Migrator._ensureTable (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/index.js:256:66)
at Migrator._listCompleted (/Users/moldot/prjx-albert/server/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/index.js:405:17)
```

I'm using postgres on my local Macbook. This is my knexfile:

```
var PostgressConnectionStringParser = require('pg-connection-string');

module.exports = {
  heroku: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    migrations: {
      directory: "migrations",
      tableName: "migrations",
    },
  },
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "moldot",
    database: "c_dev",
    migrations: {
      directory: "migrations",
      tableName: "migrations",
    },
    ssl: true,
  },
}
```

Running `psql` works fine:

```
⇒  psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U moldot -d c_dev
psql (10.1, server 9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.

c_dev=#
```

I'm running the command in the same directory that knexfile.js is in. Thank you!

Comment: maybe its heroku, that you can connect to?..

Comment: there must be another file where knex initialized based on env. Paste code from that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your knexfile has an invalid syntax. You have not given the `connection` attribute there.

It should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  heroku: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    migrations: {
      directory: "migrations",
      tableName: "migrations"
    }
  },
  development: {
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 5432,
      username: "moldot",
      database: "c_dev",
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: "migrations",
      tableName: "migrations"
    }
  }
}
```